# Dynamic store dirs for same models with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I am using CarrierWave with fog to upload my images to S3.

I have model Image that can represent images of different sizes and according to that needs to be saved in different folder.

For example, for `image.jpg` I could have two different uploaded versions that need to be saved as:

```
'images/large/image.jpg'
'images/small/image.jpg'
```

There could be arbitrary number of use cases and versions using minimagick can't cover them all.

So far I haven't been able to find solution. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this question asked a few times so I'll write what my final solution is.

Instead of defining mount_uploader on model I decided to just use Uploader independently and save urls to records later.

Dynamically changing store_dir and filename can be accomplished like this

```
uploader = Uploader.new

uploader.define_singleton_method(:store_dir) do
    'new_store_dir'
end
uploader.define_singleton_method(:filename) do
    'new_filename'
end

uploader.store!(image)
```

Using this approach you can also define names with local variables or whatever you have available in controller.

Hopefully it helps someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

in order to change where uploaded files are put, just override the store_dir method:, for your case ([reference link](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory))

```
class Image < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
storage :file
  # this if you using use condition for folder location
  def store_dir
    if model.somefield == "somecondition
       "uploads/#{model.somefield}"
    elsif model.somefield == "somecondition
       "uploads/location2"
    else
       "uploads/default_dir"
    end

  end
  # this is if you want to use version_name
  def store_dir
    'images/#{version_name}/'
  end
end
```

Comment: I need to be able to provide different dir for every image so version_name won't work. I need to have 3-4 different store dirs and choose in which one to save depending on which file field was used, is that possible?

Comment: you can use logical if inside store_dir, I just edit my answer